# Link failure when building a project with Boost and OpenSSL from Homebrew on an M1 Mac

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, openssl, arm64

I'm trying to build a C++ project that uses both Boost and OpenSSL (through the Boost::asio::ssl library).

This attempt fails with the following error message:

```bash
❯ ninja
[1/1] Linking CXX executable cproxy
FAILED: cproxy 
: && /usr/bin/clang++ -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/cproxy.dir/main.cpp.o -o cproxy   && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_ERR_lib_error_string", referenced from:
      boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int) const in main.cpp.o
  "_ERR_reason_error_string", referenced from:
      boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int) const in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My CMake file content is:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(cproxy VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS On)

# FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS asio)
# IF (Boost_FOUND)
#     message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: ${Boost_FOUND}")
#     INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
#     ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
# ENDIF()


# OpenSSL
IF (OPENSSL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    list(APPEND LIB_LIST ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
    message(STATUS "OpenSSL Version: ${OPENSSL_VERSION} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE() # Handle Apple + homebrew
    set(OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0)
    set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR}/include)
    set(OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS ${OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR}/lib)
ENDIF()

IF (Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: ${Boost_FOUND}")
ELSE()
    # Custom boost for mac - this should be passed as an env variable
    message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: NOT FOUND!! ${Boost_FOUND}")
    set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1)
    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/include)
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib)
ENDIF()

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )


message(STATUS "BOOST_ROOT: ${BOOST_ROOT}")
message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

message(STATUS "OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR: ${OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")


add_executable(cproxy main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cproxy ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Any ideas?

I'm using an M1 Mac, clang 14.0.0, cmake 3.25.3, ninja 1.11.1, boost 1.81.01, OpenSSL 3.1.0, all installed from homebrew

Expectations: build a trivial program and move on.
Result: tinkering with the build configuration until hitting a wall

Comment: You commented out the `# FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS asio)` block so you will get to the ELSE() always. You set some variables but don't use `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS asio)` so `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` is never populated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by setting `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` and using `find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)`

I'm aware it’s not the proper way to fix this - the BOOST_FOLDER and OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR variables should have been env variables since it’s not forward or backward compatible. OTOH it’s a quick and dirty test so meh

The interim version of the cmake file (not cleaned):

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(cproxy VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS On)

# FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS asio)
# IF (Boost_FOUND)
#     message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: ${Boost_FOUND}")
#     INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
#     ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
# ENDIF()


# OpenSSL
IF (OPENSSL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    list(APPEND LIB_LIST ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
    message(STATUS "OpenSSL Version: ${OPENSSL_VERSION} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
ELSE() # Handle Apple + homebrew
    message(STATUS "OPENSSL not found")
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0)
    find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
    #set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR}/include)
    #set(OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS ${OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR}/lib)
    message(STATUS "!! Version: ${OPENSSL_VERSION} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")
ENDIF()

IF (Boost_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: ${Boost_FOUND}")
ELSE()
    # Cutom boost for mac - this should be passed as an env variable
    message(STATUS "Boost_FOUND: NOT FOUND!! ${Boost_FOUND}")
    set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1)
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
    #set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/include)
    #set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib)
ENDIF()

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )


message(STATUS "BOOST_ROOT: ${BOOST_ROOT}")
message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

message(STATUS "OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR: ${OPEN_SSL_ROOT_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")


add_executable(cproxy main.cpp)

# target_include_directories(boost_asio INTERFACE /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1/include)
target_link_libraries(cproxy ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```